Smooth sharp lines between multiple materials on an object
I am trying to make an object that has been sculpted so when i try to apply a different material using edit mode the edges are jagged and pointy. I have found a way to make a smooth transition but i want it to be a distinct line between the materials but have the line be smooth and curved. I have tried splitting the object and using boolean but the ways i split it up gave me spikey edges too. Thanks so much for any help!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hello please show some images, maybe you're trying to give different materials to your faces but it would be preferable to give one material to the whole object and separate the different parts with a b&w mask?
